# I would like to install Simon Voice recognition software on Ubunu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, voice-recognition, simon

I can't find an easy way to install Simon voice recognition software on Ubuntu 18.04.  What is the easiest way?

If you know an alternative that can be installed on Debian or Ubuntu let me know. Wrist problems and a voice recognition to control my station would be more than welcome.

Comment: If you know an alternative that can be installed on Debian or Ubuntu let me know.  Wrist problems and a voice recognition to control my station would be more than welcome

Comment: I have added your comment into your post.

Comment: I found an step-by-step here : https://userbase.kde.org/Simon/Development_Environment

Answer (score 2):

Since [simon](https://blogs.kde.org/2017/03/13/new-life-simon-speech-recognition) was [dropped from the 18.04 repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sound/), installation is not easy, and requires [downloading its source code](https://simon.kde.org/download) and [compiling it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158660/will-a-package-i-compile-myself-perform-better-than-installing-from-the-reposito/158676#158676). This is non-trivial.

Alternatives? [CMUsphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/) is just a toolkit which simon uses, and [freespeech AKA OpenMindSpeech](http://freespeech.sourceforge.net/) is less. [julius](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/julius/4.2.2-0ubuntu3), another toolkit simon uses, exists and is in the 18.04 repositories, but is nowhere near as well documented as simon. Installing [julius](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/julius) is simple: open a terminal window and type in

```
sudo apt-get install julius
```

Should you find julius wanting, this article goes into great detail on an alternative [through Google Docs](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/07/speech-recognition-to-text-in-linux-ubuntu-using-google-docs/).

Comment: Is it, or is it not in the repositories?

Answer (score 2):

It's no longer in the repositories for 18.04 and hence you need to compile it from source. First pull it from the git repo using

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/simon simonsource
```

Install the build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install cmake kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-dbg kdelibs5-dev
```

And then build it

```
cd simonsource
./build_ubuntu.sh
```

Comment: Here is the Comment referred to earlier in my last Comment. Problem in ./build_ubuntu.sh - stops within a minute (notable to include all log due to restrictions on this site: Qwt 6.x include dir not found CMake Error at cmake/FindQwt6.cmake:114 (MESSAGE): Could not find Qwt 6.x Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/john/simonsource/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/john/simonsource/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: the git repo is now located at https://invent.kde.org/unmaintained/simon

Answer (score 0):

> git clone git://anongit.kde.org/simon simonsource
>
> sudo apt-get install cmake kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-dbg kdelibs5-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install libqwt-dev

Add in file: simonsource/build/simonlib/simonactions/moc_actionmanager.cpp (last line)

```
#include "../../../simonlib/simonactions/actionmanager.h" // behind this line:9
#include <QHash>                                          // add this line
```

Save file and compile.

> cd simonsource
>
> ./build_ubuntu.sh